# How to access webserver running in double NAT network from external network

Tags: iot, nat

This is not a programming question, more likely a network question. Sorry, If I shouldn't post this question here.

I'm trying to access my webservice that controls my micro-controllers GPIO from external network using my public IP, but I couldn't able to. On little research I came to know that my ISP is using double NAT and that can't be accessible from outside network. But `Blynk` app on my mobile is able to trigger my microcontroller from outside network (by registering my microcontroller with `Blynk` cloud).

My question is how `Blynk` is able to reach-out the device running behind same double NAT network.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your difficulty is in having a server initiate a connection to your device when the device is behind double NAT. The Blynk library, which you install on your device, initiates the connection outwards to a Blynk server, which is not behind any NAT. Much the same as your device can initiate an HTTP request for a website and receive a response

Once that connection between device and server is established, traffic is exchanged over that.

To do something similar you essentially want to reverse your thinking of the client/server roles. When you say you’re trying to “access the webserver [on your microcontroller]”; you’re treating your microcontroller as the server. Your microcontroller should be the initiator of the connection (usually the client role).

You can have the device initiate a socket connection to a socket server (which is what blynk is doing) or have it initiate a VPN connection (you can then use the VPN tunnel to treat the device and server as if there is no NAT)

Comment: Thanks @Tom Harvey, So is it kind of pull model that client will keep polling the server for the status or some kind of persistent connection established by my device in home network to the public server.